# Maxwell molecules, Linearized Collision Operator and Hermite Tensor Polynomials

Tags: notation, kinetic-theory

According to (1) the Hermite tensor polynomials:
$$\begin{aligned}
H^{(0)} &=1\\
H^{(1)}_i&=x_i\\
H^{(2)}_{ij} &=x_ix_j-\delta_{ij}\\
&\vdots
\end{aligned}
$$
are eigenfunctions of the linearized collision operator for Maxwell Molecules. Cercignani, 1990, also suggests something different (pg226). My naive expectation is that for this to work we would replace $x_i$ in the above with $v_i$ but this leads to dimensionally incorrect quantities. My question is therefore, what do we replace $x_i$ with to make them eigenfunctions of the linearized collision operator for Maxwell Molecules?

**References**

(1) Harris, S., 2004. *An introduction to the theory of the Boltzmann equation*. Courier Corporation. (pg106)

Comment: Could you say a bit more about "tensor polynomials" and "Maxwell Molecules"? Not all of us are able to consult the reference you give. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give more details about the setup? I don't think the dimensions really matter for an eigenfunction, as you can always just divide both sides of $Ax = \lambda x$ by some dimensionful constant.